# How make Shotwell scan only specific folder?

Tags: photo-management, shotwell

Shotwell has an option "Watch library directory for new files". I have all photos in one folder with subdirectories. So I would like Shotwell to scan for new files only this specific folder. Instead of this every time it starts it scans all the folders on my system and imports bunch of pictures which I definitely don't wanna see in Shotwell database.
Is it possible to somehow point Shotwell what exactly I want it to scan?

Answer (score 1):

Your library location is the folder which Shotwell scans. For instance in my case «Fotos» is the only folder Shotwell scans.

[image]