# How to stop shotwell from scanning entire disk on startup?

Tags: shotwell

Every time I run shotwell 0.15 (Ubuntu 13.10), it starts scanning my entire hard drive (according to ~/.cache/shotwell/shotwell.log) and displays "Updating Library." Is there a way to prevent this full-drive scan at startup? All my photos are in one directory tree and there's no need to scan elsewhere.

I checked the [shotwell manual](http://www.yorba.org/shotwell/help/) but didn't find a solution.

I tried invoking shotwell with the --no-runtime-monitoring option, but this made no difference.

I deleted ~/.cache/shotwell and ~/.locale/share/shotwell and reran shotwell, but this made no difference.

This thread asked the same question in 2012, but it did not provide a solution:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2087882

This bug sounded relevant at first but seems to be about a different issue:

- http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/3568

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: How about going to `Edit->Preferences->Library (tab)` and Uncheck watch library directory for new files. Hope that helps,

Comment: Sorry, that checkbox makes no difference. The full-disk scan happens anyway.

Comment: Looks like [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36643/how-make-shotwell-scan-only-specific-folder) relieves the symptom, sort of. shotwell scans its "Library Location." If I set it to the actual directory containing my photos, it scans only that folder instead of the whole disk. I don't see any way to prevent the scan at startup though.